Solidity Contract - Method.call() returning empty data
I have a solidity contract running on the sepolia testnet, that is just registering and fetching users. Apparently the register part works right, but the getAllUsers() part which is supposed to fetch all data just seems to be returning empty arrays (which are expected to be filled with the data sent during registration). Below is my contract. (Some sections excluded).
struct UserData {
        string email;
        string password;
        bool deleted;
    }

    mapping(string => UserData) public users;
    string[] public userIDs;

    function getAllUsers() public view returns (string[] memory, UserData[] memory) {
        UserData[] memory allUsers = new UserData[](userIDs.length);
        for (uint i = 0; i < userIDs.length; i++) {
            allUsers[i] = users[userIDs[i]];
        }
        return (userIDs, allUsers);


}

    function register(string memory id, string memory email, string memory password) public returns (bool) {
        if (bytes(users[id].email).length == 0 || bytes(users[id].password).length == 0){
            return false;
        }
        UserData memory newUser = UserData(email, password, false);
        users[id] = newUser;
        userIDs.push(id);
        return true;
    }

The returned value of the getAllUsers().call() is two arrays, but the issue is they are empty
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "0": [],
        "1": [],
        "__length__": 2
    }
}

Any insight on why it is not returning data?
Tried switching to method.send() with gas. Etherscan does record the transaction, but no data is returned

The issue is that nothing is being registered through register(), if you check its return value (true/false) it will always be false because of the invalid check.
bool ok = monate.register("3", "test3@local.com", "123456");
assert(ok == false);

Look at this invalid check
if (
            bytes(users[id].email).length == 0 ||
            bytes(users[id].password).length == 0
        ) {
            return false;
        }

I assume you intended to return false if the id is already registered which should be like this
 if (
            bytes(users[id].email).length != 0 ||
            bytes(users[id].password).length != 0
        ) {
            return false;
        }

